# Sending data using Ajax data not sending to PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to use Ajax to send some form data, but on the PHP page it's not echoing. I'm new to Ajax so not sure if I have done something wrong with it.

Here's what I have:

```
$(function () {

    $('form').on('submit', function (e) {

      e.preventDefault();

      $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        url: 'two.php',
        data: $('form').serialize(),
        success: function () {
          alert('form was submitted');
        }
      });

    });

  });
```

One of the form fields has a `name="selection"` and `id="selection"` but in `two.php` all I'm trying to do is simply:

```
echo $_POST['selection'];
```

But nothing is set.
Any ideas?

Comment: to see if you have result put this `console.log(data);` after your alert, in two.php try `$data = $_POST; $arrdata = array(); for each($data as $row) { $arrdata[] = $row; } var_dump($arrdata);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be passing your *response* (from two.php) to your `success` callback:

```
    success: function ( response ) {
      alert( 'Submitted data: ' + response );
    }
```

Which should work provided `selection` is actually set. (check in your console under network requests to confirm this)

Also, consider adding an `error` callback:

```
  error: function( response, errorThrown ){
      alert( 'request failed: ' + errorThrown );
  }
```

to report back any ajax errors.